# Getting ArcGIS online web map to update images coming from randomly generated link?

Tags: arcgis-online, csv, image, hyperlink, random

I am creating a web map that shows images from a live traffic feed. The feed, which is coming from the Texas Department of Transportation's website, updates every few minutes. When the updates happen on TxDot's website, a link is randomly generated.

That means when I copy and paste the link from the website into my CSV, I am pulling one of those randomly generated links. The links will only show the picture from when the link was pulled and will not update with the most current picture from TxDot's website.

Is there a way, either within the CSV file I am building to create the web map or within ArcGIS online, to get the most up-to-date link without having to manually input it? Each image I am trying to capture is uniquely named within the TxDot website. That unique name is used in my CSV.

I want to clarify that I have no problem getting my CSV into ArcGIS Online. I have a complete web map that looks great. My issue is that my pictures will not update because, essentially, the links expire. Is there a way to build a script that can access a website and update the link based on image name?

Comment: Got a link to the feed?  Most CCTV/Cam feeds have an API with a static request to get the most recent image.  

Creating a script to keep updating the popup with the corresponding new URL is do-able (I would use ArcGIS Python Admin API / scrapy) but I would be checking the live traffic feed API to rule out using a static URL.

Answer (score 2):

In ArcGIS Online update thats coming this week you will be able to set a refresh interval on your media images in the popup

Coming soon example link here:
https://twitter.com/pwross01/status/908001940868493312